# How to read csv file as dataframe with missing headers and data shift problem in certain rows due to extra commas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, header

I want to read this CSV file in data frame

```
Username,Identifier,First name,Last name,Department,Location
booker12,9012,Rachel,Booker,,,Sales,Manchester
grey07,2070,Laura,Grey,,,Depot,London
johnson81,4081,Craig,Johnson,Depot,London
jenkins46,9346,Mary,Jenkins,Engineering,Manchester
smith79,5079,Jamie,Smith,Engineering,Manchester
```

There is data shift in first and second row due to extra comma.

I want to read the data as it is with missing headers.

There is data shift in first and second row due to extra comma.
Now when I read it with

```
df = pd.read_csv('Commission.csv', index_col=False)
```

It throws warning ParserWarning: Length of header or names does not match length of data. This leads to a loss of data with index_col=False.

and gives output

```
    Username  Identifier First name Last name   Department    Location
0   booker12        9012     Rachel    Booker          NaN         NaN
1     grey07        2070      Laura      Grey          NaN         NaN
2  johnson81        4081      Craig   Johnson        Depot      London
3  jenkins46        9346       Mary   Jenkins  Engineering  Manchester
4    smith79        5079      Jamie     Smith  Engineering  Manchester
```

So how can I get data as:

```
    Username  Identifier First name Last name   Department    Location   Somename      Somename
0   booker12        9012     Rachel    Booker          NaN         NaN      Sales    Manchester
1     grey07        2070      Laura      Grey          NaN         NaN      Depot        London
2  johnson81        4081      Craig   Johnson        Depot      London        NaN           NaN
3  jenkins46        9346       Mary   Jenkins  Engineering  Manchester        NaN           NaN
4    smith79        5079      Jamie     Smith  Engineering  Manchester        NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use pd.merge with NaN with the right column

Answer (score 0):

Try `DataFrame.dropna()`

```
df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know *beforehand* how many columns are needed and how many are present in the first line, then you could set `header=None` and use the `names` option. With the following input

```
Username,Identifier,First name,Last Name,Department,Location
booker12,9012,Rachel,Booker,,,Sales,Manchester
grey07,2070,Laura,Grey,,,Depot,London
johnson81,4081,Craig,Johnson,Depot,London
jenkins46,9346,Mary,Jenkins,Engineering,Manchester
smith79,5079,Jamie,Smith,Engineering,Manchester
```

this

```
df = pd.read_csv("Commission.csv", header=None, names=list(range(8)))
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :6].to_list() + ["X", "Y"]
df = df.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

delivers

```
    Username Identifier First name Last Name   Department    Location      X  \
0   booker12       9012     Rachel    Booker          NaN         NaN  Sales   
1     grey07       2070      Laura      Grey          NaN         NaN  Depot   
2  johnson81       4081      Craig   Johnson        Depot      London    NaN   
3  jenkins46       9346       Mary   Jenkins  Engineering  Manchester    NaN   
4    smith79       5079      Jamie     Smith  Engineering  Manchester    NaN   

            Y  
0  Manchester  
1      London  
2         NaN  
3         NaN  
4         NaN
```

`names=list(range(8))` implicitly sets the column length to `8`, `header=None` reads the first line into the first row (instead of using it as header). Afterwards set the first `6` items of the first row and `2` additional names as final column names, drop the first row, and reset the index.